# Eclipse not recognizing the android device

Tags: android, eclipse, driver, adb

I am new to android.
My eclipse indigo recognizes one of my 2 android devices Motorola Atrix but not Motorola Droid. I am not sure what is the problem.
Both of my devices are running android 2.3.6
My device manager shows Android Phone -> Android ADB Composite Interface.
I have also enabled USB debugging but still it does not recognize my 2nd device.
I have tried going into the device manager and uninstalling the driver for droid and installing it again but still not working.

Please Help!

Comment: are you on windows or linux?

Comment: Try killing and restarting adb shell

Comment: Have you enabled developer mode in the phones settings?

Comment: I issued adb kill-server and adb start-server commands and the daemon is started successfully. Still when I do adb devices, it does not show anything.
@jimmithy I have enabled USB debugging, is developer mode something different?

Comment: See: http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html

Comment: They say developer mode is for Android 4.0 and I am running 2.3.6 so yea, I have enabled USB debugging.
Thanks for the info though, never knew it is called developer mode in ICS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

> Goto your device manager -> Right Click android adb composite interface under android phone   -> Goto the details tab ->  Select Hardware Ids Property from Scroll down.
>
> And you will see something line USB\VID_05E0&PID.....

This 05E0 is a hex number, create adb_usb.ini file and put this number inside it as 0x05E0.
Now save this file inside your .android directory. And you will see your device inside eclipse and also from command line using adb devices command.

Answer (score 1):

Under windows you might need OEM device drivers, look here:

http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html#Drivers

for motorolla you will find drivers here:

https://motorola-global-portal.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/88481

Comment: I already had Moto device manager but re-installed it. I disabled USB debugging now and connected my device and it installed the drivers. Then I re-enabled the debugging mode and issued command adb devices. It still does not show my device. But it does show my Atrix.