# Connecting Android device through Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I am not able to find my device in the list in run config even though I have enabled the usb debugging and able to read the files on my computer through the SD card. Please help

Comment: Have you been able to find other devices?  When you connect your phone to your computer, your phone should display a notification saying something like "debugging enabled".

Comment: Try to kill and restart ADB. Then be sure that you device is unlocked.

Comment: Refer to - 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13273808/eclipse-not-recognizing-the-android-device?rq=1